# Reconnect Visual Studio project to GitHub repository

Tags: c#, visual-studio, github, version-control

I've had to reformat my hard drive. I've restored my Visual Studio projects but now I need to reconnect them to their corresponding GitHub repositories.

Unfortunately, information about that connection does not appear to have been saved with my projects.

How can I re-establish the connection between my project and the GitHub repository? Preferably, without having to recreate everything or lose any work.

I have a lot of projects I will need to reconnect to their repositories.

*Note: I'm just using build-in Visual Studio commands to manage my repositories.*

*Note 2: I added one project to source control and it now shows every file as being added. I'm not sure if this was a mistake.*

**Update:**

So, I added my project to source control, and tried to publish the project to GitHub. I think this overwrites everything and I lose all my current history. But I'm not seeing other options. But this gives me an error.

> Error encountered while pushing branch to the remote repository: rejected Updates were rejected because the remote contains work that you do not have locally. This is usually caused by another repository pushing to the same ref. You may want to first integrate the remote changes before pushing again.

But the *Pull* command is disabled and says *The current branch does not track a remote branch.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order for the solution to remember your GitHub settings, you need to save the hidden *.git* folder.

My regular backup procedure did not copy this folder, although I was able to retrieve the old one.

Since I had re-added the project to source control, I could easily undo this by deleting the new *.git* folder. And I was able to copy of the original *.git* folder in its place. And when I loaded the project, all the repository settings were as they were before and Visual Studio recognized any new changes I had made.